# Implement PWA Root application In Micro-Frontend

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, micro-frontend

I have successfully integrated PWA into an angular application, and the sample runs well. How to apply same concept in a micro-frontend root application?

I have tried in angular, but how to implement MFE root.

How can I apply the successful integration of a Progressive Web App (PWA)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How to Implement Progress-web-application In Micro-Frontend